# How to stop the overflowing of an element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG icon(Font Awesome) that keeps overflowing out and getting above my navbar. I tried `overflow: hidden;` but it didn't change anything. Please help me understand and fix the problem.

UPDATE #1:

Something I have noticed that if I don't set the `position` (defaults to `static`), then it behaves just like normal. But I need to set the `position` to `relative` as I am using the `right` property to align the item. I also noticed that changing the position to anything from static creates the problem.

The HTML structure-

```
<div class="collapsible-card">
  <div class="collapsible-card-title">
    <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzlZzr16izsGHBCHIkO3H7n-UiHyZPCJFEPiQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" class="unselectable" alt="Youtuber's Logo">
    <h5>PewDiePie</h5>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="chevron-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-down fa-w-14 drop-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z">
      </path>
    </svg>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-item-container" style="display: block; max-height: 1140px;">
  <div class="collapsible-card-items">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HHZiNdrZGA" target="_blank"> 
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HHZiNdrZGA/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
      <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
         <h3>I Made The WORST Minecraft MISTAKE There Is. .. - Part 40</h3>
         <span>2020-03-13</span>
       </div>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B1f9PGLbIs" target="_blank"> 
       <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1B1f9PGLbIs/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
       <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
         <h3>I'm Back in Minecraft! - Part 39</h3>
         <span>2020-03-06</span>
       </div>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS54qL3GeaI" target="_blank"> 
       <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WS54qL3GeaI/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
       <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
         <h3>Subnautica Part 1 (OMG GAME)</h3>
         <span>2020-03-15</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq_rzA3RAmY" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq_rzA3RAmY/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>Worst TIMING I've EVER HAD in a videogame.......</h3>
          <span>2020-03-20</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq8QxKnN_5I" target="_blank">
         <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lq8QxKnN_5I/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
         <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
           <h3>LOST my HAIR, When Hearing New Meme Music! [MEME REVIEW]  #76</h3>
           <span>2020-03-03</span>
         </div>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2i-fPWWy4A" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2i-fPWWy4A/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>Video flagged for: False Information  [MEME REVIEW]  #73</h3>
          <span>2019-12-20</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS-

```
.collapsible-card {
  background-color: #353638;
  margin: 0 5px 20px 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  transition: display 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.collapsible-card-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.75em;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* background-color: rgb(107, 218, 74); */
}

.collapsible-card-title svg {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  color: #ff304f;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
}

.collapsible-card-title img {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.collapsible-card-items a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: #2d2f31;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.collapsible-card-item-info-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.collapsible-card-item-container {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #262729;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```css
.collapsible-card {
      background-color: #353638;
      margin: 0 5px 20px 5px;
      border-radius: 20px;
    
      transition: display 1.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2.75em;
      cursor: pointer;
      /* background-color: rgb(107, 218, 74); */
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title svg {
      overflow: hidden !important;
      color: #ff304f;
      margin-left: auto;
      position: relative;
      right: 25px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title img {
      width: 88px;
      height: 88px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-items a {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      background-color: #2d2f31;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-item-info-container {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-item-container {
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 0;
      background-color: #262729;
      transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-card"><div class="collapsible-card-title">
  <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzlZzr16izsGHBCHIkO3H7n-UiHyZPCJFEPiQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" class="unselectable" alt="Youtuber's Logo">
  <h5>PewDiePie</h5>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="chevron-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-down fa-w-14 drop-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
 <path fill="currentColor" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z">
 </path>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-card-item-container" style="display: block; max-height: 1140px;">
  <div class="collapsible-card-items">
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HHZiNdrZGA" target="_blank"> 
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HHZiNdrZGA/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
   <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>I Made The WORST Minecraft MISTAKE There Is. .. - Part 40</h3>
   <span>2020-03-13</span>
    </div>
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B1f9PGLbIs" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1B1f9PGLbIs/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
    <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>I'm Back in Minecraft! - Part 39</h3>
   <span>2020-03-06</span>
    </div>
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS54qL3GeaI" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WS54qL3GeaI/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
    <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>Subnautica Part 1 (OMG GAME)</h3>
   <span>2020-03-15</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq_rzA3RAmY" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq_rzA3RAmY/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
  <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
    <h3>Worst TIMING I've EVER HAD in a videogame.......</h3>
    <span>2020-03-20</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq8QxKnN_5I" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lq8QxKnN_5I/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
   <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
     <h3>LOST my HAIR, When Hearing New Meme Music! [MEME REVIEW]  #76</h3>
     <span>2020-03-03</span>
   </div>
    </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2i-fPWWy4A" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2i-fPWWy4A/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
  <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
    <h3>Video flagged for: False Information  [MEME REVIEW]  #73</h3>
    <span>2019-12-20</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not understanding what `svg` is here, would you share a screen shot of that svg and where you want to get it placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you were not setting `svg` image `height` `width`, I set it to `20px` you can change it according to your requirement

Second use `z-index:1111` on your `header/nav` to make you `svg` icon behind header

```css
.collapsible-card {
      background-color: #353638;
      margin: 0 5px 20px 5px;
      border-radius: 20px;
    
      transition: display 1.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2.75em;
      cursor: pointer;
      /* background-color: rgb(107, 218, 74); */
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title svg {
      overflow: hidden !important;
      color: #ff304f;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: 25px;
      width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-title img {
      width: 88px;
      height: 88px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-items a {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      background-color: #2d2f31;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-item-info-container {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .collapsible-card-item-container {
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 0;
      background-color: #262729;
      transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-card"><div class="collapsible-card-title">
  <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzlZzr16izsGHBCHIkO3H7n-UiHyZPCJFEPiQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" class="unselectable" alt="Youtuber's Logo">
  <h5>PewDiePie</h5>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="chevron-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-down fa-w-14 drop-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
 <path fill="currentColor" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z">
 </path>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-card-item-container" style="display: block; max-height: 1140px;">
  <div class="collapsible-card-items">
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HHZiNdrZGA" target="_blank"> 
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HHZiNdrZGA/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
   <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>I Made The WORST Minecraft MISTAKE There Is. .. - Part 40</h3>
   <span>2020-03-13</span>
    </div>
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B1f9PGLbIs" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1B1f9PGLbIs/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
    <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>I'm Back in Minecraft! - Part 39</h3>
   <span>2020-03-06</span>
    </div>
  </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapsible-card-items">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS54qL3GeaI" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WS54qL3GeaI/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
    <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
   <h3>Subnautica Part 1 (OMG GAME)</h3>
   <span>2020-03-15</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq_rzA3RAmY" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq_rzA3RAmY/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
  <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
    <h3>Worst TIMING I've EVER HAD in a videogame.......</h3>
    <span>2020-03-20</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq8QxKnN_5I" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lq8QxKnN_5I/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
   <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
     <h3>LOST my HAIR, When Hearing New Meme Music! [MEME REVIEW]  #76</h3>
     <span>2020-03-03</span>
   </div>
    </a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapsible-card-items">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2i-fPWWy4A" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2i-fPWWy4A/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
  <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
    <h3>Video flagged for: False Information  [MEME REVIEW]  #73</h3>
    <span>2019-12-20</span>
  </div>
   </a>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something I have noticed that if set the '.collapsible-card-title SVG' position to static, then it behaves just like normal. But I need to set the position to relative as I am using the right property to align the item.

Comment: Then use `margin-right: 25px;` and remove `position` ,`right:25px`, That solve your problem, Update my answer, and also set `header/nav z-index:1111`

Comment: OK then try second approach set z-index of you blue header to 11111

Comment: That seems to solve the problem. From my understanding, there was a problem with the z-index cause the elements that come later have a higher stacking order and that is why the SVG element kept popping up, right?

Comment: Yes Glad that helps, Accept it as an answer i also update z-index solution as well

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly then you want the svg to be at right side?

The size of the `svg` you used is bigger than what you need, so you need to provide a `height` and `width` for the same, for understanding purpose I have added a border `white`. You can go ahead and remove that border and set your own `height` and `width` and you all set.

use `z-index:1`(or to a larger integer, I assume there are no `z-index` element used for the header) on your **blue** header so that the icon will stay underneath the `header`.

```css
.collapsible-card {
  background-color: #353638;
  margin: 0 5px 20px 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: display 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.collapsible-card-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.75em;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* background-color: rgb(107, 218, 74); */
}

.collapsible-card-title svg {
  height: 50px; /* use your desired height as per your requirement */
  color: #ff304f;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  border:1px solid white;
}

.collapsible-card-title img {
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.collapsible-card-items a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: #2d2f31;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.collapsible-card-item-info-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.collapsible-card-item-container {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #262729;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-card">
  <div class="collapsible-card-title">
    <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzlZzr16izsGHBCHIkO3H7n-UiHyZPCJFEPiQ=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" class="unselectable" alt="Youtuber's Logo">
    <h5>PewDiePie</h5>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="chevron-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-down fa-w-14 drop-icon" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M207.029 381.476L12.686 187.132c-9.373-9.373-9.373-24.569 0-33.941l22.667-22.667c9.357-9.357 24.522-9.375 33.901-.04L224 284.505l154.745-154.021c9.379-9.335 24.544-9.317 33.901.04l22.667 22.667c9.373 9.373 9.373 24.569 0 33.941L240.971 381.476c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible-card-item-container" style="display: block; max-height: 1140px;">
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HHZiNdrZGA" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HHZiNdrZGA/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>I Made The WORST Minecraft MISTAKE There Is. .. - Part 40</h3>
          <span>2020-03-13</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B1f9PGLbIs" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1B1f9PGLbIs/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>I'm Back in Minecraft! - Part 39</h3>
          <span>2020-03-06</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS54qL3GeaI" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WS54qL3GeaI/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>Subnautica Part 1 (OMG GAME)</h3>
          <span>2020-03-15</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq_rzA3RAmY" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq_rzA3RAmY/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>Worst TIMING I've EVER HAD in a videogame.......</h3>
          <span>2020-03-20</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq8QxKnN_5I" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lq8QxKnN_5I/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>LOST my HAIR, When Hearing New Meme Music! [MEME REVIEW]  #76</h3>
          <span>2020-03-03</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-card-items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2i-fPWWy4A" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K2i-fPWWy4A/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Video's Thumbnail">
        <div class="collapsible-card-item-info-container">
          <h3>Video flagged for: False Information [MEME REVIEW]  #73</h3>
          <span>2019-12-20</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said by setting the height and width of the SVG but the problem persists. Though something I have noticed that if set the position to static, then it behaves just like normal. But I need to set the position to relative as I am using the right property to align the item.

Comment: Don't you think the code which is added above, gives an exact thing what you asked? what difference you see from the above code?

Comment: I have updated the post with new information. I think it can be important information. Kindly read it.

Comment: .collapsible-card-title svg {
  height: 35px;
  width:35px;
  color: #ff304f;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  border: 1px solid white; 
} this has position: relative and it also works for `right` property, I would like to see what is not working if you can attach an image even after adding this code in your snippet.

Comment: I got it now! you have to use `z-index:1`(blue title) this will set the icon underneath the header title!